# Why doesnt this compile with go 1.10 compiler but will run on goplayground

Tags: go, utf-8, interface

I need to know why this code will not compile, the go compiler keeps telling me im using an invalid-utf encoding, but I don't understand exactly where this is occurring. The error I'm receiving.

```
$ go build Example#2.go
command-line-arguments
.\Example#2.go:32:15: invalid UTF-8 encoding
```

Any help at all on this would be most appreciated. I know its a simple program but its to demonstrate the language to my programming languages class and this is just supposed to be a simple example showing how method names have to be linked to structs and how interfaces work. Like I said this works on `go playground` but not with the actual compiler.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Person struct {
    Name    string
    Address Address
}

type Address struct {
    Number string
    Street string
    City   string
    State  string
    Zip    string
}
    type Citizen struct {
    Country string
    Person
}
type speak interface {
    Talk()
}

func (p *Person) Talk() {
    fmt.Println("Hi, my name is", p.Name)
}

func (p *Person) Location() {
    fmt.Printf("I’m at %v %v %v %v %v\n", p.Address.Number, 
    p.Address.Street, p.Address.City, p.Address.State, p.Address.Zip)
}

func (c *Citizen) Nationality() {
    fmt.Println(c.Name, "is a citizen of", c.Country)
}
func (c *Citizen) Talk() {
    fmt.Println("this is the citizen talk method")
}
func Converse(s speak) {
    s.Talk()
}

func main() {
    p := Person{
        Name: "Jim",
        Address: Address{
            Number: "1",
            Street: "College Avenue",
            City:   "exampleland",
            State:  "StateLand",
            Zip:    "8675309",
        },
    }
    c := Citizen{}
    c.Name = "John"
    c.Country = "Somewhereland"
    c.Person.Address.Number = "1337"

    c.Person.Address.Street = "Haxor Lane"
    c.Person.Address.City = "Lazy"
    c.Person.Address.State = "Foo"
    c.Person.Address.Zip = "192.168.1.1"

    p.Talk()
    p.Location()

    ///////////////
    fmt.Println("")
    ///////////////

    c.Person.Talk()
    c.Talk()
    ///////////////
    fmt.Println("")
    ///////////////
    c.Nationality()
    c.Location()
    ///////////////
    fmt.Println("")
    Converse(&p)
    Converse(&c)
}
```

Comment: `go 1.10.1` here, it compiles and runs fine.

Comment: Have you looked at the file in a hex editor to see if there are some funky bytes in there?

Comment: No I havent, but  it doesnt seem to have this issue when I run on my linux VM for work, its centos7 and my personal machine that its having compile issues on is windows 10 home.

Comment: Thank you mu, I would have never thought of using a hex editor as I have never used them before, but I downloaded one, and bam, a single character wasnt registering correctly in UTF-8, it was the apostrophe " ' ".

Comment: `' ` is a totally valid character. It's safe to use it in go string literals.

Comment: Yeah but that apostrophe that was originally used wasn't, im not exactly sure why, but when I looked at it through a hex editor, it showed that it was a "."(period) and was flagged red as a non UTF-8 encoded character. Its probably because I ripped the initial example off of some website. once I replaced it  with the UTF-8 apostrophe it ran just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this was caused by the apostrophe in "I'm" //>> fmt.Printf("I’m at %v %v %v %v %v\n", p.Address.Number,p.Address.Street, p.Address.City, p.Address.State, p.Address.Zip)